# jasper-reports generate empty pdf in linux

Tags: java, linux, pdf, fonts, jasper-reports

1. i have used jasper-reports 3.*
2. my application-server is jboss
3. OS is windows : every things is ok and generated pdf shown correctly

but the problem is:
1. when OS is Linux : generated pdf is empty

caused by :
1.maybe for fonts not exist!!

> i have tried these ways :
>   1.copy all necessary fonts in my application's class path
>   2.install all necessary fonts on Linux machine
>   3.copy all necessary fonts in JRE/lib/fonts

but problem still not resolved ...

any help will be appriciated?

Comment: What do you mean when you say your PDF is empty. If you mean that you can see all the pages, but that they are all blank, then you are probably "shaving bytes." PDF originated as an ASCII format in 1993, but soon it was changed into a binary format. All the "structure" is still in ASCII, but the content of the pages is usually stored as a binary stream. If you treat the binary PDF as a plain text, then the structure is preserved, but not the page streams. As a result you only see blank pages. Is that the case for you?

Comment: yes all page generated but all of them is blank , and just images and borders shown correctly and Any text is not displayed

Comment: If lines are displayed, your problem is not what I initially thought. Fonts could be the issue.

Comment: i think so , the fonts is the issue , but what is the solution !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your Linux using OpenJDK , this is the problem , OpenJDK has problem with regular fonts and some graphical charts , to resolve problem install  " sun/Oracle jdk " , all issue will be done

Answer (score 1):

The fonts are often the problem in jasper. You can package your needed fonts in your application like this:

1. Create a file called jasperreports_extension.properties
2. Add following lines to this properties file:

`net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.arialfontsfamily=fonts/arial/arialfontsfamily.xml`

3. Add the font description xml in the directory fonts/arial/ (file should be named as defined in your properties file -> arialfontsfamily.xml)

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <fontFamilies>
      <fontFamily name="Arial">
           <normal><![CDATA[fonts/arial/Arial.ttf]]></normal>
           <bold><![CDATA[fonts/arial/Arial_Bold.ttf]]></bold>
           <italic><![CDATA[fonts/arial/Arial_Italic.ttf]]></italic>
           <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/arial/Arial_Bold_Italic.ttf]]></boldItalic>
           <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
           <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
           <exportFonts>
               <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
               <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
           </exportFonts>

      </fontFamily>
   </fontFamilies>`
4. Add the fonts in the directory fonts/arial

   - Arial.ttf
   - Arial_Bold.ttf
   - Arial_Italic.ttf
   - Arial_Bold_Italic.ttf

According to this how-to you can add all your fonts to your application, so that you don't need to be concerned about which OS the code is executed.

The example above for using fonts **Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif**

Some explanations:

- With  you tell jasper that the fonts should be included in the pdf

Comment: thanks for your solution , but is it works in jasper-report 3.0.1 !? , what version i should use !?

Comment: This feature is supported since version 3.1.3

Comment: i have got Jasper 3.7.1 and use fonts extension , it work correctly in windows but in Linux some text shown but some not , and all charts has a problem to show !!! realy i don't know what is the problem , maybe the pdf generator ( itext 2.7.1.jar )  do not work correctly !!!

Comment: i have some report that design with Birt report in the same project , all reports with Birt work correctly in both windows and Linux !!! But jasper ...

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen during the font issue. I have overcome these issues using the below commands.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

After the install needs to restart your server.If you work on tomcat.Need to restart it.